# Find the original three terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

*$x$, $y$, and $\frac3{2x}$ are non-zero terms in an arithmetic progression. If the third term is increased by $1$, the three terms now form a geometric progression. Find the original three terms.*

Here are my steps:

1) The numbers were set into a proportion to find the common ratio.
$\dfrac xy = \dfrac{\tfrac3{2x}}y$

2) The equation was set equal to $0$ such that $0=\tfrac32x^2-y^2$

I do not know how to move on from here or if the steps lead to the correct answer. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: It's wrong. What you are doing is treating the original sequence as a geometric progression but what the question says is the original sequence is arithmetic.

Comment: @cr001 In that case, do I find the common difference?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.